# Graph API - Automate Getting Emails (Delegated Permissions)

Tags: azure, rest, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm developing a background application (no user interaction will be possible) and I want to automate getting all emails from certain mail boxes using the Graph API. I am facing some issues though:

1. If I use application permissions I get access to every mailbox in the organization which is not a good solution. Is it possible to limit the access to certain mailboxes? We are using On-premise Exchange and not Exchange Online so this link is not relevant (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access).
2. It I use delegated permissions the app will need user interaction (as far as I can tell) but that will not be possible as it should run in the background. I am looking at the different flows for authentication but none of them really fit my need. Maybe it can be done with the Refresh Token Flow but it seems vulnerable. Is it possible to use delegated permissions without user interaction? If yes, what is the best approach?

Best regards
J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you couldn't use [delegated permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#permission-types) without user. Delegated permissions are used by apps that have a signed-in user present.

It seems [Resource Owner Password Credentials(ropc) flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) which allows an application to sign in the user by directly handling their password is the best choice for you. But it carries risks, please see the *Important* in the article to make sure you can use it. You should only use this flow when other more secure flows can't be used.

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=<client_id>
&scope=user.read%20openid%20profile%20offline_access
&username=MyUsername@myTenant.onmicrosoft.com
&password=<password>
&grant_type=password
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I guess that would actually work - only issue is that it does not support personal accounts - and I don't think I will be allowed to get my organizations resource owner's credentials. Can you recommend a second best option?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot find another suitable flow. The client credential flow uses application permission but limits the app access to a specific set of mailboxes to only Exchange Online resources. The other flows such as auth code flow, implicit flow need to sign in with a user.

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, thank you.