# MSFT Graph API for SharePoint (restrict app to only certain users, groups or folders)?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am working on creating a server daemon process for automated ingesting of files from SharePoint to a private server. This is a headless (no user) app that runs via a "cron" job. So my reading of the OATH protocol indicates to me that we cannot use the /authorize or /adminconsent endpoints, since they ask for a redirect_uri (and there is no human to reply here). Correct me if I am wrong.

In OneDrive we created a group site, and also a tenant (clientID and secretID) for it and gave the daemon (not delegate, since there is no user) but application level permissions for Microsoft Graph and File.Read.All

This is all working fine, we authorize and get the bearer token by doing the 2-legged OAUTH (known in MSFT as OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow) by calling the tenant/token endpoint in the graph server site. No problem getting files either.

Except that the daemon can now read any SharePoint or OneDrive folder in our system. Not really good security practice.

Is there a way of setting up the access token so that it is restricted to only the SharePoint Document folder of the SharePoint Team that we have?

I have seen a SO question which asks a similar request:
[Graph API - Automate Getting Emails (Delegated Permissions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67632287/graph-api-automate-getting-emails-delegated-permissions)

But I do see lots of warnings in trying to use the proposed solution:
ROPC = OAuth 2.0 Resource Owner Password Credentials

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc

So is there some preferred way to restrict the bot/agent (i.e. ACLs?)

If we have to use ROPC, and create a dummy user, what access do we give that user in AD? And what do we need for the Graph API (tenantID, username, password, and client-secret?).

Comment: In my humble opinion, folders in onedrive can be set as sharing to specific users, then we can create a group in azure ad and add all these users into that group, then [set azure ad app can only be accessed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/assign-user-or-group-access-portal) by users in this group.

Comment: This idea can be summarize as: in your own application, it provides a login module and allow users to sign in, but your app also validates the user roles(roles are defined in azure ad app) then those have correct role can sign in your app, then your app generate access token to call graph api to deal with onedrive. You onedrive also set a validation to make sure only those users can edit the shared folder....

Comment: My ingest files app is a bot. There is no user. It runs on schedule from a server that is external to azure.

Comment: `no user` and `created a server daemon process`, so if you want your bot to access the graph api, then you can only using client credential flow to generate access token, this follow doesn't require a user to sign in. In this scenario, can your bot know who's now trying to access graph api throught the bot? If not, then `restrict this to only certain users` can only be done by onedrive(share folder to specific users). But I'm not sure if it can work, I didn't test it before... If your bot don't know who's doing the operation, then  how onedrive can know who's trying to access it?... Sorry sir.

Comment: @TinyWang I rewrote the question, and I think it answers your questions and makes the problem clearer.